# prevent links in html form fields

Tags: html, forms, hyperlink

Is there a way to prevent a form from being submitted if it contains links.
I would like to prevent links from being added to input: question and message field.

Can anyone point in the right direction for info?
thanks

```
<div class="form">
        <form id="sbwd_contact" method="post" action="http://whatanswered.com/forms/ask/ask.php">
            <em class="error"></em>
            <input type='hidden' name='sfm_form_submitted' value='yes'/>
            <label for="Email">E-Mail: </label>
            <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email" size="30" class="required email" />
            <label for="question">Question: </label>
            <input type="text" id="question" name="question" size="30" class="required" />
            <label for="Message">Additional Info: </label>
            <textarea name="Message" cols="30" rows="6" id="Message" class="required"></textarea>
            <br />
            <p><span>I Agree to the Terms and Conditions
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Terms_and_conditions" value="I agree" class="required"/></span></p>
            <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Send" />
            <br /><br />
            <p><a href="http://whatanswered.com/terms-and-conditions.php" target="_blank">View our Terms and Conditions</a></p>
        </form>
```

Comment: By "link", do you mean the HTML tag or any URL? If the tag, use a server-side HTML sanitiser. If a URL, you can make do with [a good URL regex](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) (Actually those might be overkill if all you need is to know whether a URL is present, it might be sufficient to just look for `://`)

Comment: Thanks for the info i will look into that, I keep getting spam mail from the form which contains between 3 and 8 links and urls so i want to prevent form submission if contains links or urls.

Answer (score 5):

Add this before insertion in database

```
if(preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|http):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$_POST['question'])){

// prevent form from saving code goes here
 echo "<script>alert('Please remove URLs');</script>"; 
}
else{
 // Insertion in Db
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the form from actually being *submitted* you would need to use JavaScript to suppress the bubbling of the submit event. Specifically I would recommend using jQuery, something like this:

```
$(document).ready($(document).on('submit', function()
 { if ($("#question:contains('href=')").length > 0) return false; });
```

I might be wrong, but it *looks* like you are trying to achieve some sort of simple protection against spam or cross-site-scripting (XSS). If so, this is probably not the best technique, since, like all client-side security, it can easily be bypassed. Better would be to use a regular expression to strip out such links on the server-side *after* the post. Or for spam prevention, use a proper Bayesian/keyword filter, such as implemented by many WordPress plugins. Remember, a spammer can still market his product without a hyperlink. I think you will find that trying to prevent spam by stopping posts with hyperlinks will not be sufficient for a semi-popular blog or talkback section. All sorts of other types of spam, e.g. stock market three-letter-code pump-and-dump, brand dropping, or brand FUD, can be effective without hyperlinks.

Also keep in mind that there are many different ways for the user to inject potentially harmful HTML/JS/SQL code into the posts. The best technique is to strengthen your *handling* of user input, rather than restricting input altogether. For example, on Stack Overflow, users can post HTML/JS code samples. SO doesn't want to prevent that input, so they make sure to *escape* it whenever it's sent back to the browser, rendering it totally harmless. See this article for more info: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can check if your input field contains one or more substrings like 'HTTP://' and if so end the script with an error.
Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you are posting an HTML script, and you'r asking about PHP, so you are not showing any effort. Having said, that..

If I had wanted to prevent links from being submitted into a form, I could use `strip_tags()` function of PHP to strip all `<a` `>` from what the user is entering, and thus changing the link to just raw text. Alternatively from PHP side, you could use `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` to validate if URL has been submitted:

```
 $url = "http://www.mywebsite.com";

if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
  echo "No URL detected";
  }else{
  echo "URL is found";
  }
```

And work your way up from there.